# Using a Function pointer inside a class crashes the compiler (but works inside a function)

Tags: class, visual-c++, c++-cli

Reference class

```
class commandsListClass
{
public:
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    std::vector<std::string> commands;
    columnHeaders headersRequired;
    void (*function)(System::Object ^ );
    std::string recoveryFileHeader;
    void reset()
    {
        name = "";
        description = "";
        commands.clear();
        headersRequired.reset();
        recoveryFileHeader = "";
        function = dummyFunc; // dummyFunc uses the same members as the intended - this is to ensure it is defined. DummyFunc is empty, returns void etc
    }
    commandsListClass()
    {
        reset();
    }
};
```

Currently, if I run the below code, the compiler crashes

```
// This crashes the compiler
System::Threading::ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem(gcnew System::Threading::WaitCallback(global::commandsList[index].function ), ti);
```

[image: Visual of the crashed compiler]

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>  project.cpp
1>c:\users\guy\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\MyProject\MyProject\Form1.h(807): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1443)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I declare a member inside the same function as I am making the call, and set it to the global::commandsList[index].function, it compiles and runs correctly

```
// This runs correctly    
void (*func)(System::Object ^);
func = global::commandsList[index].function;
System::Threading::ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem(gcnew System::Threading::WaitCallback(func ), ti);
```

global::commandsList is a vector of type commandsListClass

Any ideas? Browsing Google and SO suggest changing the compiler to not optimize, which I've tried with no success. The code is written in such a way that:

- That point in the code cannot be reached if index does not point to a valid member of the global::commandsList vector
- The function variable is guaranteed to be set, either to the dummyFunc on creation, or the correct (requested) function as set elsewhere in the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: This is using Visual Studio 2012, Windows 7 x64

Comment: My suggestion would be to store a `gcroot<WaitCallback^>` instead of a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified repo:

```
public delegate void MyDel(Object^);

void g(Object^) {}

struct A {
    static void(*fs)(Object^);
    void(*f)(Object^);
    gcroot<MyDel^> del;
};

void(*fg)(Object^);

void h()
{
    void (*f)(Object^);
    A a;

    gcnew MyDel(f);
    gcnew MyDel(fg);
    gcnew MyDel(a.fs);
    a.del = gcnew MyDel(g);

    //gcnew MyDel(a.f);  // this line fails

    // work around
    f = a.f;
    gcnew MyDel(f);
}
```

Only the non-static member variable fails. Seems like a compiler bug. Work around it by using a local intermediate.

Or better is Lucas's suggestion to use gcroot.

Comment: Thanks, but the idea to use a local member was in the question already, which I ended up doing for simplicity.